# How to add to list elements via slicing?

Tags: python

How can I add an int to a range of  in a list?

For example, if I need to add 7 to elements between and including index `(a,b)`, why isn't my code working?

```
k = 7
a = 0
b = 2
List = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
List[a:b+1] += k
```

This throws me an error: "int" object is not iterable.

My expected output is `[8,9,10,4,5,6]`.

Comment: Addition involving multiple elements works for `numpy` arrays, but not lists.  You have to replace the elements of the list one by one.

Comment: The `+` sign on list tries to extend the list with the given argument, which should be an `iterable`. In your cas, `k` (`7`) isn't, that's why you get an error. Try `[1, 2] + [3, 4]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a for loop to iterate over the list.

```
for i in range(a, b+1):
    List[i] += k
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
new_list = List[0:a] + map(lambda x : x + k, List[a:b+1]) + List[b+1:]
```

Output :

```
>>> new_list
[8, 9, 10, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: This won't be correct. First, it's highly inefficient, beause `.index` is a linear operation, so it will be quadratic in the length of the interval. Second, `.index` returns the index of the **first** instance in the list, so this will break your logic.

Comment: For example, try it with `[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]` with the same values for a,b, and k.

Comment: How about now ? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: I mean, that works, it's just honestly quite clunky and doesn't modify the list in-place implied by the OP. And it's probably better to use a list comprehension rather than `map` with `lambda`.

Comment: Probably better keeping the spirit of your original attempt: `[e + k if a <= i <= b else e for i, e in enumerate(List)]` . But honestly, the OP should just use a for-loop.